# Google Speech recognition API stops recording after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-speech-api

This is the code to recognize speech, it stops recording in a few seconds. The mic icon from the Title Bar vanishes.

```
var streaming = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
streaming.lang = 'en-IN';
streaming.continuous = true;
streaming.interimResults = true; 

streaming.onresult = function(event) {
  l_pos = event.results.length - 1 ;
  console.log(event.results[l_pos][0].transcript);
}

streaming.onend = function(event) {
  console.log("1")
  streaming.start();
  console.log("2")
}

streaming.start();
```

How do I make it record continuously?

Comment: Remove streaming.stop(); from the code. That is stopping the recording..

Comment: Removed the line but it still stops recording if I dont talk for ~10 seconds.

Comment: Ok. if you want  to record continuously then you can do  one thing. There is an onstop or onend event. in that event you can start it again..

Comment: @AjuJohn it worked. Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want  to record continuously then you can do  one thing. There is an onstop or onend event. in that event you can start it again..